# How to get file name having particular content in it using java?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, file-io, hashmap

Here I am trying to read a folder containing .sql files and I am getting those files in an array, now my requirement is to read every file and find particular word like as join if join is present in the file return filename or else discard , someone can pls help me with this ..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Filter {

    public static List<String> textFiles(String directory) {
        List<String> textFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File dir = new File(directory);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith((".sql"))) {
                textFiles.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        return textFiles;

    }

    public static void getfilename(String directory) throws IOException {
        List<String> textFiles = textFiles(directory);
        for (String string : textFiles) {
            Path path = Paths.get(string);
            try (Stream<String> streamOfLines = Files.lines(path)) {
                Optional<String> line = streamOfLines.filter(l -> l.contains("join")).findFirst();
                if (line.isPresent()) {
                    System.out.println(path.getFileName());
                } else
                    System.out.println("Not found");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        getfilename("/home/niteshb/wave1-master/wave1/sql/scripts");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at methods like `File.lines()` which give you the ability to search the content of a file as text.

Comment: I have added it but it doesnt seem working @Thomas

Comment: Note: `textFiles.add(file.getName());` just adds the _name_ of the file to your list but `Files.lines(path)` needs a full path. Assuming the files are not in your current working directory you need to store the file's path as well. - Also: "it doesn't seem working" is rarely helpful, you should always add context, e.g. in what way it fails (what do you expect and what do you get?) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search word in file as belwo, pass the *path* of file

```
try(Stream <String> streamOfLines = Files.lines(path)) {
  Optional <String> line = streamOfLines.filter(l -> 
                       l.contains(searchTerm))
                       .findFirst();
  if(line.isPresent()){
   System.out.println(line.get()); // you can add return true or false   
  }else
   System.out.println("Not found");
}catch(Exception e) {}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Filter {

    public static List<String> textFiles(String directory) {
        List<String> textFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File dir = new File(directory);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith((".sql"))) {
                textFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(textFiles.size());
        return textFiles;

    }

    public static String getfilename(String directory) throws IOException {
        List<String> textFiles = textFiles(directory);
        for (String string : textFiles) {
            Path path = Paths.get(string);
            try (Stream<String> streamOfLines = Files.lines(path)) {
                Optional<String> line = streamOfLines.filter(l -> l.contains("join")).findFirst();
                if (line.isPresent()) {
                    System.out.println(path.getFileName());
                } else
                    System.out.println("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return directory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        getfilename("/home/wave1-master/wave1/sql/");
    }
}
```